# Hiding edges in QGIS vector symbology

Tags: qgis, symbology, vector

I have a vectorized layer of slope percentages that I want to visualize with a gradual color change without showing the black edges between different values.

I managed to do a color gradient visualization with the graduated symbols option. However there is black edge around each feature representing a different slope value. Is it possible to hide this black edge somehow, so that it will look like a gradual change rather than having these chunky triangulated black lines in between the different shades

Comment: You got several good answers to your vector symbology question, but I need to ask, why did you vectorize the slope raster in the first place if you wanted a continuous color ramp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Symbology pane, above your graduated colour classes, click the `Symbol` selector bar.

[image]

Then select the `Simple Fill` symbol layer, and change the stroke style to `No Pen`

[image]

Comment: @J.R, that is a nice approach and probably deserves its own anwser. However, testing with 3.26.3, I cannot get it to work. The *Preview* of the evaluated expression at the bottom of the expression editor gives what looks like the correct value (e.g. `#f7fbff`), but this is not being picked up by the renderer. If I copy-paste the same hex code as a string in the expression, it does work, however.

Comment: Ah, I just realised what is happening. The features themselves receive the desired style, but the preview for the classes in the styling panel does not update accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could achieve the desired symbology by clicking on the symbol icon right below the graduated symbology setting definition. On the new symbology window click on Simple marker/line and set the stroke style as "No pen". This operation should remove the black edge that is the default setting.
[image: Symbology panel]

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

To complete the other good answer here is another way that prevent the faint white line between polygon (visible in the first picture below) that you may get by using the "no pen" stroke style (these white line are more visible if adjacent polygon are close in color and also seem more visible when you export the map)
[image]

To prevent this use data defined properties on the stroke color of your symbol with the `@symbol_color` expression.
This will set the stroke color to the same color as the fill and hide the white line (remember to set the stroke style to "Solid Line" and to choose an appropriate stroke width)
[image]

This solution is also useful if you want a polygon border to be the same color as the fill but a bit lighter or darker : just use `darker(@symbol_color , factor)` or `lighter(@symbol_color , factor)` (remplace "factor" the value that give the best result for you)

Comment: Great, for now I will just set it to no Pen, as thats the easiest way and gives a good enough result. Thank you!